# How to compile and run a vmmlib test program?

Tags: c++, syntax, gnu

I have successfully installed vmmlib 1.7 using the following steps:
Downloaded the files from https://github.com/VMML/vmmlib/tree/1.7 
and followed the steps below:

```
mkdir vmmlib/build
cd vmmlib/build
cmake ..
make
```

Now, I'm trying to run a program in the test folder "t3_hosvd_test.cpp" , but I'm not able to run it.
I tried to run the Makefile but got the following error:

```
svd_test.cpp:13:0:
../include/vmmlib/vmmlib.hpp:33:30: fatal error: vmmlib/version.hpp: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
: recipe for target 'svd_test.o' failed

 make: *** [svd_test.o] Error 1
```

I also tried to run by giving the following command in the terminal:

`g++ t3_hosvd_test.cpp -lapack -lvmmlib`

but got an error:

```
  t3_hosvd_test.cpp:2:31: fatal error: vmmlib/t3_hosvd.hpp: No such file or directory
  compilation terminated.
```

**Can someone help me compile and run this program on Ubuntu 16.04?**

Comment: `vmmlib` seems to be badly maintained or not maintained.

Answer (score 0):

When compiling directly, you need to provide the include path via the `-I` option.

`g++ t3_hosvd_test.cpp -I/usr/local/vmmlib17/include -lapack -lvmmlib`

Also ensure that your include path is set to vmmlib/include and not vmmlib/include/vmmlib